Difference of Sum of Remainders for $499$ and $500$.

Bluey divides the number $499$ by each of the numbers $1,2,3, . . . , 499$ and records the remainders in order. So her sequence begins: $0,1,1,3,4,1, . .$ . Let $M$ be the sum of these $499$ remainders. Jean-Luc divides the number $500$ by each of the numbers $1,2,3,...,500$ and records the remainders in order. So his sequence begins:$0,0,2,0,0,2, . . .$ Let $N$ be the sum of these $500$ remainders.What is the difference between the numbers $M$ and $N$?

Here is how I started it (I did it online): 

Then, $1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 + 20 + 25 + 50 + 100 + 125 + 250 − 499.$
I understand that a table is also a viable solution too.
However, I would appreciate a quicker and faster solution than the above for this question because it is from a mathematical competition (solving $30$ questions in $60$ minutes). Thank you very much.

If you make a chart of the factors of numbers:
$$\begin{array} {}
1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 \\ \hline 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 & 2& &2 & &2 & &2 \\
 & &3 & & &3 & & \\
 & & &4 & & & &4 \\
 & & & &5 & & & \\
 & & & & &6 & & \\
 & & & & & &7 & \\
 & & & & & & &8 \\
\end{array}$$
You can see a lot of patterns.  One of them is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor n / k \rfloor \cdot k$$
Where the left side references the divisor function, it is adding the columns; the right side is adding the rows.
So $$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n n - (n \bmod k) = n^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n (n \bmod k)$$
So if $g(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (n \bmod k) = n^2 - f(n)$, then $g(500) - g(499) = 500^2 - 499^2 - \sigma(500)$.  Not sure how you are supposed to know that in 2 minutes though, rough question.
FWIW $\gcd(a,b)=1 \implies \sigma(ab) = \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$, so $\sigma(500) = \sigma(2^2)\sigma(5^3) = (1 + 2 + 2^2)(1 + 5 + 5^2 + 5^3)$
